# ArrayList field not correctly gathered

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

I'm actually new at Kotlin, and I encounter the following problematic:

> I have a class holding an ArrayList of EnsembleVerifier class.
>   This other class is instantiated with an ArrayList of Square.
>   When I tried to get this ArrayList, I discovered that this one has no element inside.

Is there any absurdity/misconception in my code? Is it something else? Thank you in advance! :)

GridVerifiers.kt

```
class GridVerifiers(private val grid: Grid) {
   private var verifiers: ArrayList<EnsembleVerifier> = ArrayList()

   init {
      generateVerifiers()
   }

   private fun generateVerifiers() {
      generateLineVerifiers()
      generateColumnVerifiers()
      generateSubGridVerifiers()
   }

   private fun generateLineVerifiers() {
      val line: ArrayList<Square> = ArrayList()

      for (lineIndex in grid.gridState.indices) {
         for (columnIndex in grid.gridState.indices)
            line.add(grid.gridState[lineIndex][columnIndex])
         println(line.size) // returns 9
         verifiers.add(EnsembleVerifier(line))
         line.clear()
      }
   }

   ...
```

EnsembleVerifier.kt

```
class EnsembleVerifier(private val squares: ArrayList<Square>) {

   ...

   fun isValid(): Boolean {
      val buffer: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
      println(squares.size) // returns 0!
      for (square in squares) {
         if (square.value in buffer) return false
         buffer.add(square.value)
      }
      return true
   }
```

Comment: I think is because you are calling `line.clear()`. 
You are not copying the object but passing a reference and then deleting the content of the array.

Therefore, when you call clean you are cleaning the ArrayList that you have just passed to the EnsembleVerifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java most of the time you are working with references to objects. This means in your case, that your are always working with the same array `line`. Therefore, when you call [`line.clear`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/clear.html) you are cleaning the array that that reference is pointing at, and that's causing your issue with empty arrays.

You need to generate new objects every time instead of cleaning the list.

```
private fun generateLineVerifiers() {
  for (lineIndex in grid.gridState.indices) {
    val line: ArrayList<Square> = ArrayList()    
    for (columnIndex in grid.gridState.indices)
      line.add(grid.gridState[lineIndex][columnIndex])
    println(line.size) // returns 9
    verifiers.add(EnsembleVerifier(line))
  }
}
```